# Allow only predefined devices to connect to my device via IP tables

Tags: iptables

I want to allow only a few specific connections in Ubuntu Core-16.

- Allow SSH connection
- Allow MQTT connection to a specific broker address from MQTT client in my device.
- Allow REST client ip  to connect to the server on my device.

The problem I'm facing is connection with MQTT because of the following settings:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This is how I'm setting specific IP from a txt file:

```
input="/home/admin/ip.txt"

while read line; do
var=$line
#echo "var= $var"
var1="$(cut -d' ' -f 1 <<< $var)"
echo "string = $var1"
case $var1 in
     jumper)
          #echo "Thank you"
          #echo "Your type: jumper"
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
          port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          ;;
     mqtt)
          #echo "Thank you"
          #echo "Your type: mqtt"
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
          port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          ;;
     rest)
          #echo "Thank you"
          #echo "Your type: rest"
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
          port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          ;;
     server)
          #echo "Thank you"
          #echo "Your type: server"
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
          port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          ;;
     *)
          echo "Sorry, invalid input"
          ;;
esac

done < $input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the result in following way(make sure proper IP addresses and ports are filled up in `ip.txt` file):

First make everything connectable to avoid losing existing connections by running the following 3 commands on terminal:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Then, flush all the existing IP tables settings:

```
iptables -F
```

Finally run the script that blocks all the connections and then enables only the IPs those are mentioned in `IP.txt` file (sample of this file at the end):

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

while read line; do
var=$line
var1="$(cut -d' ' -f 1 <<< $var)"
case $var1 in

     jumper)
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
      port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
      iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -s $ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
      iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport $port -d $ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT          
      ;;

     mqtt)
      ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
      port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
      iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport $port -s $ip -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
      iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $port -d $ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          ;;

     rest)
      ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
      port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -s $ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
      iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport $port -d $ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
      iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
          ;;

     server)
      ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
      port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
          ;;

     rangeJumper)
          ip="$(cut -d' ' -f 2 <<< $var)"
          port="$(cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $var)"
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range $ip --dport $port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m iprange --dst-range $ip --sport $port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
          ;;

     *)
          echo "Sorry, invalid input"
          ;;
esac

done < $input
```

*Sample IP.txt file:*

```
jumper 10.100.100.249 22
jumper 10.100.100.76 22
mqtt 10.100.99.238 8883
rest 10.100.100.76 34568
rest 10.100.100.249 34568
server 10.100.100.76 154
rangeJumper 10.100.99.71-10.100.99.100 22
rangeJumper 10.100.97.72-10.100.97.100 22
```